# How do I destroy (completely reset) the blockchain?

Tags: nodeos

Is there a nodeos command-line switch to just destroy the entire blockchain state and start over from the first block? Or can I achieve this by deleting one or more specific directories that are stored somewhere?

I have a vanilla EOSIO 1.6.1 binary release installation on Ubuntu 18. I don't know where the blockchain data is stored.

Answer (score -1):

Found it.

```
~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/
```

I just deleted the "nodeos" directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos
```

Comment: I did rm -rf ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos but still unable to start nodeos even with the hard_replay option .